# mysql all records and columns selected, but when i select a particular column it doesn't work

Tags: mysql, select

table `location` has 3 columns: zip_id, city, state

i can:

```
SELECT * FROM location;

SELECT zip_id, city, state FROM location WHERE zip_id="94116";

SELECT zip_id, city, state FROM location WHERE city="san francisco";
```

but can't:

```
SELECT zip_id, city, state FROM location WHERE state="CA";
```

no data is returned. how come? thank you in advance.

Comment: Is that `CA` the exact string? No spaces?

Comment: What is the value for state column for that record? It could be California and you are searching for abbreviation

Comment: Nin-ya:  you're right ... changed `state` varchar(30) to varchar(2) and now it works. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than = you should use `like`

```
SELECT zip_id, city, state FROM location WHERE state like '%CA%';
```

= will match exact string so make it like with `%` that will do wildcard matching

Comment: then there must not be a record with  CA

Answer (score 0):

What worked is modifying `state` varchar(30) to varchar(2).